# Create CUstom Page Layout in Thesis

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am a beginner in wordpress and in that I am using thesis theme and i was stopped at one place and don't know the solution for that place.

**Question is**:

I want  to create custom page template in thesis theme so don't know how to do this.
so how to create **custom_template** in wordpress ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For create custom template create file in your activated theme's folder. fo example if your custom template name is "home_custom_template".
Write code inside your file :

```
    <?php
    /*
    Template Name: home_custom_template
    */
    get_header();
    ?>
          /*
             Your Php and html code here...
          */

 <?php get_footer();?>
```

1))

```
     /*
        Template Name: home_custom_template
     */
```

this code define to wordpress this is template.

2))
 Create new page In wordpress, right side of page one dropdown for template. you can find your template there. So, choose your custom template and publish page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom Template in Wordpress & Store it in your current theme in which you are working

```
<?php
/* Template Name: ContactTemplate (like this try giving any logical name so that while using this template you can Remember it by name, this is for Contact page Template)
?>
<?php get_header(); //this will call your header files ?>
<?php 
//your content goes here 
//you can run custom Query here, try running query_posts(); if you want to show posts
?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Note:- here header, footer & sidebar will remain same for all pages